# Extract 2 different double from a string

Tags: java, string, double, extract

Ok so I'm trying to extract 2 different doubles from a string created by this

```
 line=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter infos in this format name:hours@cashperhour");
```

Name is a String, hours is a Double and cashperhour is a Double too

I sucessfully extracted the string by doing this

```
 name=line.substring(0,line.indexOf(":"));
 System.out.print(name);
```

But it fails with the double

```
 hours=Double.parseDouble(line.substring(line.indexOf(":", line.indexOf("@"))));
  System.out.print(hours);
```

If try it with for example Robert James:34@45 I get

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
```

And if I try without the "@" Robert James:34 I get

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ":34"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help me ? Sorry if it's not written correctly it's my first post here

Answer (score 0):

You could use `split(...)` since the values are delimited by `:`

```
String[] data = line.split("\\:");
String name = data[0]; 
String[] numbers = data[1].split("@");
double hours = Double.parseDouble(numbers[0]);
double cashperhour = Double.parseDouble(numbers[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tested and working**

Try this:

```
    String data = "Enter infos in this format name:hours@cashperhour";
    String[] split_data = data.split(":",2);
    String[] between = split_data[1].split("@",2);

    //Your doubles:
    System.out.println(between[0]);
    System.out.println(between[1]);
```

Also, for the double Test:

```
    String data = "Enter infos in this format name:1.2@5.4";
    String[] split_data = data.split(":",2);
    String[] between = split_data[1].split("@",2);

    //Your doubles:
    System.out.println(between[0]);
    System.out.println(between[1]);
    double hours = Double.parseDouble(between[0]);
    double cashperhour = Double.parseDouble(between[1]);
```

**This compiles for me:**

```
public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "Enter infos in this format name:1.2@5.4";
    String[] split_data = data.split(":",2);
    String[] between = split_data[1].split("@",2);

    //Your doubles:
    System.out.println(between[0]);
    System.out.println(between[1]);
    double hours = Double.parseDouble(between[0]);
    double cashperhour = Double.parseDouble(between[1]);

}

}
```

Comment: The `split(...)` method takes a regular expression as an argument, you need to escape the `:` character.

Comment: Yes you are right, it works even if you don't escape the `:` character, I think that is because `:` is not considered as a regex operator on its own. I don't know that much about regex.

Comment: Ya I use split() all the time :) You can even use: split(Pattern.quote("!@#$"),2)

Comment: I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

Comment: No problem, please mark as the correct answer for future viewers!